# Calculating distances from capital city using coordinances [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, coordinates, distance

I have a 2 large dataframes containing various variables, 
I need to add variable ***distance_from_capital_city***, 
that would be defined as folows:

One dataframe has all country names and capital cities and their coordinances (cap_coordinances in exaple below)
and I have another dataframe that has some variables in same countries sometimes in capital city sometimes not.

I need to add variable ***distance_from_capital_city*** to real_data dataframe (in example below)
and the result should look like this:

First 4 rows of variable ***distance_from_capital_city*** in dataframe ***real_data*** should be equal to zero (or some small number because coordinances do not have to match exactly and rounding error etc.)
and last fifth row should contain distance from Barcelona to Matrid (grouped_by country).
Distance should be measured in kilometrs from capital city, or any euclidian distance or any other suitable measuremeent.

Using for example this funtion:

```
library(geosphere) distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)
```

I gave example of the result (numbers are for ilustration)

```
library(tibble)
cap_coordinances = 
  tribble(
  ~country_txt, ~city, ~longitude, ~latitude, 
  "Greece",             "Athens",       23.8,       37.9,
  "Italy",              "Rome",         12.5,       41.9,
  "Netherlands",        "Amsterdam",     4.90,      52.4,
  "Spain",              "Madrid",       -0.743,     41.0,
)

real_data = 
tribble(
  ~country_txt,        ~city,  ~longitude,  ~latitude,
                "Greece",      "Athens", 23.762728, 37.99749,
                 "Italy",        "Rome", 12.490069, 41.89096,
  "Netherlands",        "Amsterdam",     4.90,      52.4,
  "Spain",              "Madrid",       -0.743,     41.0,
           "Spain",     "Barcelona",   2.15, 41.3

)

result = 
  tribble(
    ~country_txt, ~city,  ~longitude, ~latitude, ~distance_from_capital_city,
    "Greece", "Athens", 23.762728, 37.99749, "0 or small number",
    "Italy", "Rome", 12.490069, 41.89096, "0 or small number",
    "Netherlands", "Amsterdam", 4.90, 52.4, "0 or small number",
    "Spain", "Madrid", -0.743, 41.0, "0 or small number",
    "Spain", "Barcelona", 2.15, 41.3, 3500

  )
```

I cannot solve this issue on my own, So I would like to ask for any advice

Data I am using are public can be downloaded here:

Comment: In the `real_data`, the lat, long are different for the city

Comment: Yes - the results for capital cities should be very small number or zero as I wrote. For not capital cities should be mutch bigger

Comment: Can you show your expected output as there are different ways  to calculate the distance

Comment: Sorry I dont understand

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'capital_city' and 'city' as column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a join and then calculate the difference between the corresponding 'latitude', 'longitude' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
real_data %>% 
    left_join(cap_coordinances, by = 'country_txt') %>% 
    transmute(country_txt, city = city.x,
     distance = pmap_dbl(.[c('longitude.x', 'latitude.x', 
   'longitude.y', 'latitude.y')], 
      ~ distm(c(..1, ..2), c(..3, ..4), fun = distHaversine) %>% as.vector)) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  country_txt city      distance
#  <chr>       <chr>        <dbl>
#1 Greece      Athens      11335.
#2 Italy       Rome         1300.
#3 Netherlands Amsterdam       0 
#4 Spain       Madrid          0 
#5 Spain       Barcelona  244775.
```

Comment: Sorry result should be distance in kilometrs - one number

Comment: Distance should be calculated by for example this function: `library(geosphere)
distm(c(lon1, lat1), c(lon2, lat2), fun = distHaversine)`

Comment: it seems to be right but with my real data is Not working

Comment: @Petr Is there any error message or is it something else

Comment: No just the result dont make sense. But that is mostly problem on my side

Comment: @Petr Not clear though.  Is it because the input is not correct

Comment: Yes, but data are public, from public dataset, can I somehow provide data in Rdataset? So one can see how to do it

Comment: @Petr If the data is a .csv link or so, can be able to read it

Comment: Data are avaible here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aha5nHo4JhEaq0dQTjhq76u_Bhtl?e=bDaZDr

Comment: I post the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207436/discussion-between-petr-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do it using sp. The sf solution would be similar using `st_distance` and you could use pipes. I just find the coercion to a spatial object more straight forward with sp. Do note that since your data is in decimal degrees distance is based on great circle distance and is in Kilometers.

```
library(tibble)
library(sp)

cap_coordinances = 
  tribble(
  ~country_txt, ~city, ~longitude, ~latitude, 
  "Greece",             "Athens",       23.8,       37.9,
  "Italy",              "Rome",         12.5,       41.9,
  "Netherlands",        "Amsterdam",     4.90,      52.4,
  "Spain",              "Madrid",       -0.743,     41.0,
)

real_data = 
tribble(
  ~country_txt,        ~city,  ~longitude,  ~latitude,
   "Greece",           "Athens", 23.762728, 37.99749,
   "Italy",            "Rome", 12.490069, 41.89096,
   "Netherlands",      "Amsterdam",     4.90,      52.4,
   "Spain",            "Madrid",       -0.743,     41.0,
   "Spain",            "Barcelona",   2.15, 41.3
)

coordinates(cap_coordinances) <- ~longitude+latitude
coordinates(real_data) <- ~longitude+latitude

d <- spDists(real_data, cap_coordinances, longlat = TRUE) 
  rownames(d) <- real_data$city
  colnames(d) <- cap_coordinances$city
print(d)
```

Comment: And how would you add that matrix values back to dataframe as a new value? But thank you very mutch

Comment: Sorry I just realized I need distance of cities within each country - So just distance in Spain between madrid and Barcelona, But not Madrid and Rome since these cities are not within same country